# How to prevent my temporary horse from disappearing after Hosea stables mission?

Tags: red-dead-redemption-2

Just after the gang had set up the new camp at the beginning of chapter 2, I found a random event where a guy gets killed by his horse. I took the horse which has some pretty good stats, bonded with him and kept him as a "temporary horse" until Hosea's stables mission.

The thing is, when I do the stables / grizzly hunt mission, this horse disappears and after that I only have the horse from chapter 1 and the horse they force me to buy in stables.

Knowing that I can't unsaddle the chapter 1 horse (this action is taught by Hosea in the mission and is therefore not available before), is there a way to make the random event temporary horse my main horse, or another action that could let me keep the temporary horse after Hosea mission ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Totally forgot I had posted this question here. I actually found the way to keep the American Saddlebred after the stables mission :

- Hitch the horse near the place where Hosea's black horse will appear during the mission.
- Launch the mission, and when Hosea asks you to take your saddle and equip it on the black horse, equip it to the American Saddlebred instead (Hosea may scold you because you're not doing what he's asking but it does not end the mission). This makes the American Saddlebred your new primary horse, and the tutorial's Tennessee Walker your temporary horse.
- Finish the mission by selling the black horse and fighting the grizzly, then you will be able to get your American Saddlebred in the stables which are now unlocked.

Unfortunately you will lose your first horse in the process, but after all his stats are very low compared to the American Saddlebred.

Comment: Doesn't work, it causes me to fail the mission.

Answer (score 1):

[Apparently](https://www.reddit.com/r/reddeadredemption/comments/9tdx56/get_my_horse_back_after_hosea_mission/), it should still be availabe in the stable. 

Stables will be unlocked at the beginning of Chapter 2, during *Exit Pursued by a Bruised Ego*.

Answer (score 1):

I can't comment on the other answer, but that link is referring to the original horse you get in the introduction, the Tennessee Walker.

Temporary horses will never show up in the stables.

I had the very same thing happened to me. I found that encounter where the American Saddlebred lethally kicks his owner, early-on, and I kept it. I was careful to keep it hitched at camp so it wouldn't disappear, but once I got back from Hosea's quest, it was gone.

I don't know if temporary horses disappear from camp after not being rode-on for so many in-game days, or if it's a bug with this quest. But now I suspect it's the latter.

The stables are still locked at this point, so you can't stable him.

I'm afraid there's nothing you can do.

Comment: It may be too late, but after many tries I achieved to keep the American Saddlebred after Hosea's mission, I posted the way to do it in a new answer. Thanks for helping though !

Answer (score 0):

Move saddle to the black shire. DON'T GET ON! Re hitch your temporary horse. Then mount the Shire/ complete mission. The temporary horse will be there when you get back. Then I took the temp horse into the stables and was able to sell the original Kentucky horse. TIP! Then I did the first bounty hunt mission, got the free Hungarian Half Bred. After saving that when to painted sky for the debt owed to the gang. There is another Hungarian Half Bred in the barn free! One temp. And I kept the Standard Bred too. Hope that helps.